# Stream and parse a large collection (not array) of json objects from a file

Tags: json, go

I need to stream and parse a json of the following format from a large json file?  I have tried the usual method of which only parses an array, but it fails for the following format.

```
{
    "ABCD": {
        "name": "John",
        "cars": [],
        "nums": [],
        "id": "52000"
    },
    "WXYZ": {
        "name": "Jone",
        "cars": [],
        "nums": [],
        "id": "32000"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Show your code, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a type representing the values:

```
type Value struct {
    Name string
    Cars []string
    Nums []int
    ID   string
}
```

Use the json.Decoder in [stream mode](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-Decoder.Decode-Stream) mode to read the top-level object. See commentary for details.

```
func decodeStream(r io.Reader) error {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r)

    // Expect start of object as the first token.
    t, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if t != json.Delim('{') {
        return fmt.Errorf("expected {, got %v", t)
    }

    // While there are more tokens in the JSON stream...
    for dec.More() {

        // Read the key.
        t, err := dec.Token()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        key := t.(string) // type assert token to string.
        

        // Decode the value.
        var value Value
        if err := dec.Decode(&value); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // Add your code to process the key and value here.
        fmt.Printf("key %q, value %#v\n", key, value)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Use it like this:

```
err := decodeStream(f) // f is the *os.File
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wUCvPC1ZrrV).

Comment: Thank you so much! Works. I did come up with a solution, but this is so much more cleaner.